# Why does centering not work with calligra?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying out the calligra package for a wedding order of service. Just trying to make the titles look a little nicer. When I use the \centering command, however, it doesn't seem to work:

```
\centering
Test1\\
\calligra{Test}
```

Produces calligraphic text that doesn't seem to be centered. Is this fixable?

[image: calligra not centered]

Thanks all,

James

Comment: For a very ornate font some manual adjustment is almost inevitable you need \hspace*{-.5em}Test or something, to correct for the fact that the T make a big hole in the visual appearance of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what @DavidCarlisle was suggesting in his comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\begin{document}

  \centering
  {Test1}\\
  \hspace*{-0.5em}%%
  {\calligra Test}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

You can help yourself visualize the center by doing something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{calligra}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt} % just for the example
\def\visualCenter{%%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%%
     \makebox[0pt]{\rule{2cm}{0.4pt}}%%
     \makebox[0pt]{\color{blue}\rule[-0.75cm]{2em}{0.4pt}}%%
     \makebox[0pt]{\color{red}\rule[-1in]{0.4pt}{2in}}%%
    }}
\begin{document}

  \centering
  \visualCenter\\
  {Test1}\\
  \hspace*{-0.5em}{\calligra Test}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

It is centered. The italic effect creates an illusion. And the alignment is decided by regard to the bottom of the letters.

**And**, in your example, "test1" is obviously larger than "test" (because of the "1").

The original example with `\fbox` to testify the centering:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calligra}
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt} % just for the example
\begin{document}
\centering
\fbox{Test1}\\
\fbox{\calligra Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The calligra font is smaller than the normal one but it is centered.