# Latex + TikZ: How to horizontally centre text in a node with a calligraphy font?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I want to produce rectangles with horizontally centered text.
However the outcome of my code produces rectangles where the text is NOT centered.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,a4paper,25pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[11pt]{moresize}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\input Sanremo.fd
\newcommand*\initfamilySanRemo{\usefont{U}{Sanremo}{xl}{n}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\input ArtNouvc.fd
\newcommand*\initfamilyArtNouvc{\usefont{U}{ArtNouvc}{xl}{n}}

\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{Center}
                                                                    \foreach \n in {Heinrich, Justus, Julius}{\par

  \normalfont\calligra
  \begin{tikzpicture}[align=center]

    % \draw (0,0) rectangle (108mm,41mm) node[pos=.5, align=center] {\Huge\fontsize{40}{70}\selectfont\n};
    \node (rect) [rectangle, draw, minimum width=108mm, minimum height=41mm] at (0,0) {};
    \node [below] at (rect.north) {\Huge\fontsize{40}{70}\selectfont\n};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{5mm}

}


\end{Center}
\end{document}
```

The rectangle containing 'Hendrik' shows that the centering is not perfect.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with that line replaced by `\node [below] at (rect.north) {\Huge\fontsize{40}{70}\selectfont\fbox{\n}};` to get a box around your words, it may help visualizing where the problem stands.

Comment: Is it a bit better if we add some padding around the names, like so : `\foreach \n in {\!Heinrich,\,Justus,\,Julius}{\par` ?

Comment: See [Why does centering not work with calligra?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150071/124842)